# Convert JSON to Map

Tags: java, json, parsing, collections

What is the best way to convert a JSON code as this:

```
{ 
    "data" : 
    { 
        "field1" : "value1", 
        "field2" : "value2"
    }
}
```

in a Java Map in which one the keys are (field1, field2) and the values for those fields are (value1, value2).

Any ideas? Should I use Json-lib for that? Or better if I write my own parser?

Comment: I have written code for this without using any library.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/jsonobject-to-map/24012023#24012023

Answer (score 440, accepted):

I hope you were joking about writing your own parser. :-)

For such a simple mapping, most tools from http://json.org (section java) would work.
For one of them (Jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#5-minute-tutorial-streaming-parser-generator), you'd do:

```
Map<String,Object> result =
        new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
```

(where JSON_SOURCE is a File, input stream, reader, or json content String)

Comment: Moreover, if you want a typed Map  (exploiting java generics), you can do : Map<String, MyPojo> typedMap =  mapper.readValue(jsonStream, new TypeReference<Map<String, MyPojo>>() {});

Comment: If you work with Maven project, you will need   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.4</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: And looks like Jackson has moved since 09 so: [Jackson data-bind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#1-minute-tutorial-pojos-to-json-and-back)

Comment: @obe6 I guess the OP is not joking. Can you find a single "JSON" anywhere in your code snippet other than that arbitrary variable name? I'm struggling too because of the names in Jackson API.

Comment: FWTW, while @obe6's answer is technically correct, you can use shorter form too: `Map<String,Object> result = mapper.readValue(source, Map.class)`.

Answer (score 49):

Using the GSON library:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reclect.Type;
```

Use the following code:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map>>(){}.getType();  
Map<String, String[]> son = new Gson().fromJson(easyString, mapType);
```

Comment: java at its best: `TypeToken<Map<String, Map>>` :-)

Comment: With new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>> it will work also when there are arrays inside.

Answer (score 37):

I like [google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.
When you don't know structure of json. You can use

```
JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
```

and then you can work with json. e.g. how to get "value1" from your gson:

```
String value1 = root.getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("field1").getAsString();
```

Comment: This can throw NullPointerExceptions 5 different ways if you get unexpected data.

Comment: You can use .path() now and it won't throw a NPE

Answer (score 19):

Use JSON lib E.g. http://www.json.org/java/

```
// Assume you have a Map<String, String> in JSONObject jdata
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Iterator<String> nameItr = jdata.keys();
Map<String, String> outMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
while(nameItr.hasNext()) {
    String name = nameItr.next();
    outMap.put(name, jdata.getString(name));

}
```

Answer (score 15):

My post could be helpful for others, so imagine you have a map with a specific object in values, something like that:

```
{  
   "shopping_list":{  
      "996386":{  
         "id":996386,
         "label":"My 1st shopping list",
         "current":true,
         "nb_reference":6
      },
      "888540":{  
         "id":888540,
         "label":"My 2nd shopping list",
         "current":false,
         "nb_reference":2
      }
   }
}
```

To parse this JSON file with GSON library, it's easy :
if your project is mavenized

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use this snippet :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

//Read the JSON file
JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("/path/to/the/json/file/in/your/file/system.json"));

//Get the content of the first map
JsonObject object = root.getAsJsonObject().get("shopping_list").getAsJsonObject();

//Iterate over this map
Gson gson = new Gson();
for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
    ShoppingList shoppingList = gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), ShoppingList.class);
    System.out.println(shoppingList.getLabel());
}
```

The corresponding POJO should be something like that :

```
public class ShoppingList {

    int id;

    String label;

    boolean current;

    int nb_reference;

    //Setters & Getters !!!!!
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 6):

With google's Gson 2.7 (probably earlier versions too, but I tested 2.7) it's as simple as:

```
Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);
```

Which returns a Map of type `class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` and works recursively on nested objects.

Answer (score 6):

I do it this way. It's Simple.

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{ \"f1\":\"v1\"}");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObj.toString(),Map.class);
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach buts its not working ... can you answer for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329223/how-to-update-existing-json-file-in-java/60329607#60329607

Answer (score 5):

This way its works like a Map...

```
JSONObject fieldsJson = new JSONObject(json);
String value = fieldsJson.getString(key);

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, but you must wrap every single ´get´ in try/catch because of JSON exceptions.

Comment: you could write a class, `JsonMap implements Map<String,Object` to wrap JSONObject. then you get the true `Map` interface.

Comment: Please add used libraries.

Answer (score 4):

```
java.lang.reflect.Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> categoryicons = gson.fromJson(json, mapType );
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using org.json, JSONObject has a method `toMap()`.
You can easily do:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = myJsonObject.toMap();
```

Answer (score 3):

The JsonTools library is very complete. It can be found at [Github](https://github.com/branscha/lib-jsontools).

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
  public static Map<String, Object> convertJsonIntoMap(String jsonFile) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
            mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });
            map = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One more alternative is [json-simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/) which can be found in [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1):

```
(JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(someString); //JSONObject is actually a Map.
```

The artifact is 24kbytes, doesn't have other runtime dependencies.

Comment: I get `null` back from a simple JSON string where one of the values is an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you need pure Java without any dependencies, you can use build in Nashorn API from Java 8. **It is deprecated in Java 11.**

This is working for me:

```
...
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
...

public class JsonUtils {

    public static Map parseJSON(String json) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("javascript");

        String script = "Java.asJSONCompatible(" + json + ")";

        Object result = engine.eval(script);

        return (Map) result;
    }
}
```

**Sample usage**

JSON:

```
{
    "data":[
        {"id":1,"username":"bruce"},
        {"id":2,"username":"clark"},
        {"id":3,"username":"diana"}
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
...
import jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSONListAdapter;
...

public static List<String> getUsernamesFromJson(Map json) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();

    JSONListAdapter data = (JSONListAdapter) json.get("data");

    for(Object obj : data) {
        Map map = (Map) obj;
        result.add((String) map.get("username"));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON to Map always gonna be a string/object data type. i have GSON lib from google.
Gson library working with string not for complex objects you need to do something else

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code, it worked for me,

```
Map<String, Object> retMap = new Gson().fromJson(
                myJsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can convert json string to hash map. I am the maintainer of the project.

Code example:

```
import com.github.underscore.U;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{"
            + "    \"data\" :"
            + "    {"
            + "        \"field1\" : \"value1\","
            + "        \"field2\" : \"value2\""
            + "    }"
            + "}";

       Map<String, Object> data = (Map) U.get((Map<String, Object>) U.fromJson(json), "data");
       System.out.println(data);

       // {field1=value1, field2=value2}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject

JSONObject.fromObject(yourJsonString).toMap
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON to Map always gonna be a string/object data type. i haved GSON lib from google.

works very well and JDK 1.5 is  the min requirement.

Comment: How did you use GSON?