# Creating BSON object from JSON string

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

I have Java app that takes data from external app. Incoming JSONs are in Strings. I would like to parse that Strings and create BSON objects.

Unfortunate I can't find API for that in Java's BSON implementation.

Do I have use external parser for that like GSON?

Comment: Thank You Hank for answer. I will use Jakcson because, I think GSON can't crate map from object.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do that either, even though their `JsonObject` gives you a way to get a `Set<Map.Entry>`; I wonder why they made that particular decision.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way seems to be to use a JSON library to parse the JSON strings into a `Map` and then use the [`putAll`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/BSONObject.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) method to put those values into a `BSONObject`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map/583634#583634) shows how to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial) to parse a JSON string into a `Map`.

Answer (score 56):

... And, since 3.0.0, you can:

```
import org.bson.Document;

final Document doc = new Document("myKey", "myValue");
final String jsonString = doc.toJson();
final Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);
```

Official docs:

- [Document.parse(String)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/Document.html#parse-java.lang.String-)
- [Document.toJson()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/Document.html#toJson--)

Answer (score 46):

Official MongoDB Java Driver comes with utility methods for parsing JSON to BSON and serializing BSON to JSON.

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

DBObject dbObj = ... ;
String json = JSON.serialize( dbObj );
DBObject bson = ( DBObject ) JSON.parse( json );
```

The driver can be found here:  https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/

Comment: is there any alternate available for the same in C#?

Comment: @Sunny this question is about Java and I don't know about C#, look into the Mongo C# driver source, there must be utility methods like the ones above

Comment: I'm sure this is way too late for Sunny but for anyone else stumbling across this the equivalent in C# is just `BsonDocument.Parse`

Answer (score 18):

Use `Document.parse(String json)` from `org.bson.Document`. It returns `Document` object which is type of `Bson`.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't the accepted answer. I obviously misinterpret the question.

Comment: @TomQuarendon maybe because this answer has been posted 8 years after the question. Even yair's answer which is basically the same but posted 3 years earlier, has not been chosen as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

To convert a string json to bson, do:

```
import org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder;
import org.bson.BSONObject;

BSONObject bson = (BSONObject)com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(string_json);
BasicBSONEncoder encoder = new BasicBSONEncoder();
byte[] bson_byte = encoder.encode(bson);
```

To convert a bson to json, do:

```
import org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder;
import org.bson.BSONObject;

BasicBSONDecoder decoder = new BasicBSONDecoder();
BSONObject bsonObject = decoder.readObject(out);
String json_string = bsonObject.toString();
```

Comment: the library for this code is [`org.mongodb:bson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson)

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [bson4jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) project, which allows you to use Jackson data binding to work with BSON (create POJOs from BSON, write as BSON) -- especially since Jackson also work with JSON. So it will allow conversion like you mention, just use different ObjectMapper instanstaces (one that works with JSON, other with BSON).

With Jackson you can either work with full POJOs (declare structure you want) or with simple Maps, Lists and so on. You just need to declare what to type to bind to when reading data (when writing, type is defined by object you pass).

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the answer to your question in the source code of https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/jsobj.cpp
Which has the BSON to JSON conversion.

Basically, stuff like

- `ObjectId("XXX")` -> `{ "$oid" : "XXX" }`
- `/XXX/gi` -> `{ "$regex" : "XXX", "$options" : "gi"  }`

and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the toJson() and parse(String) methods of the BasicDBObject, because the JSON utility class has been @Depricated.

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;

public static BasicDBObject makeBsonObject(String json) {
    return BasicDBObject.parse(json);
}

public static String makeJsonObject(BasicDBObject dbObj) {
    return dbObj.toJson();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about java but the mongoDB CPP driver has a function type

> BSONObj fromjson(string)

which returns a BSONObj according to the string passed. There should be a same function in Java too.