# A bridge between MongoDB DBObject and org.json.JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, org.json

I'm using the native MongoDB driver and API, which uses `com.mongodb.DBObject` to represent JSON objects, however for general purpose I have usage of `org.json.JSONOBject`.

I thought of replacing it and using DBObject as a general JSON library, but it doesn't feel right.

But to interop with the two, the low level String/Map format/parse interface is used, which I don't like either.

Is there a known library out there that implements both interfaces for easier interoperability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, converting between BSON and JSON was intended to be a painless operation, so you shouldn't have to write more classes.  Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117167/creating-bson-object-from-json-string) answer help at all?

Comment: Yes, a little, but I can't help but wonder if there isn't something like the `org.w3c.Node` as a common interface for all JSON implementations. Maybe something in Scala...

Comment: Since BSON was written by 10gen and JSON by a different source, I do not know of any common implementation.

Comment: -1 for a bad answer that links to a bad answer that links to an answer that isn't relevant here. What you're really saying is: convert the org.json object into a json string then parse it back as a DBObject. That's not what OP is asking for.