# Mongo Cannot cast Hashmap to BasicDBObject

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I've been working on a java program that makes use of a Mongo database to store certain data about airplanes based on geo coordinates. The application is working to the point as where it is gathering the information and filling up the model objects in the correct way.

When I try to send the object towards the mongo database I get the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.hashmap cannot be cast to com.mongodb.basicDbObject.` The problem with this exception: I don't have a HashMap (or any type of Map in general)

To add the object to the database I use the following code:

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection(GRID_NAME);
GridCell c = cell.getCell(true);
String jString = (String) mapper.writeValueAsString(c); //mapper is a Jackson ObjectMapper
System.out.println(jString);
table.insert((BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(jString));
```

In here the grid cell contains two floats and a List of Plane objects. The plane object contains one string and another 10 double values. Other then that the classes only have basic getters and setters for all variables.

**GridCell**

```
private float lat;
private float lng;
private List<Plane> planeList;
```

**Plane**

```
private String identiefier;
private double minHeight;
private double maxHeight;
private double avgHeight;
private double minSpeed;
private double maxSpeed;
private double avgSpeed;
private double minCourse;
private double maxCourse;
private double avgCourse;
```

**A getter and setter (all look more or less the same as these two)**

```
public float getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(float lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}
```

As you can see above I'm printing the json string to the console to check if it is correct. I have to admit my plain json reading skills are dodgy at best. But I can't find a hashmap in this:

```
{"lat":28.0,"lng":5.0,"planeList":[{"identifier":"myTestPlane","minHeight":1.0,"maxHeigh":2.0,"avgHeight":1.5,"minSpeed":1.0,"maxSpeed":2.0,"avgSpeed":1.5,"minCourse":1.0,"maxCourse":2.0,"avgCourse":1.5}]}
```

Any idea's or suggestions what I'm doing wrong? I might have a Monday morning moment but I really can't figure it out.

Comment: `JSON.parse` is probably producing a HashMap. What library are you using there?

Comment: @Thilo org.mortbay.util.ajax.JSON

Comment: That won't know anything about MongoDB. I think there is also `com.mongodb.util.JSON`. Try that one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12261133/14955

Comment: @Thilo As soon as I hit "add comment" that came to mind. I'm testing it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the "wrong" JSON library.

If you want MongoDB's `DBObject`, you can use `com.mongodb.util.JSON`.

```
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

DBObject bson = ( DBObject ) JSON.parse( json );
```

If you have an existing Map from somewhere else, you could also try to start with a `new BasicDBObject()` and `putAll` the data into it.

Comment: All test are green, I'll accept the answer in a few minutes (stack overflow has a timer on it). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up that DBObject is not recommended and using Document is encouraged: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.1/bson/documents/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Vambo. I however choose to use DBObjects over documents for the following reasons: The limitations of a DBObjects do not bother my application (the missing option of Map<String,Object> is somewhat annoying but manageable). Secondly the whole application is spread out as services. Objects are already passed in between of these in json. The code above is a simplified example, normally the object would arrive in the service as json and instead of serializing it to an object and then creating a document I rather just cast it to a DBObject and send it on its way.

Comment: I think you could accomplish the same using `Document.parse()`, no need for any intermediate cast.

Comment: I did not know that was there. I'll give it a try, thank you!