# Mongo Document with DBRef

Tags: java, mongodb, dbref

There are many example how work  with mongo document
[Creating BSON object from JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117167/creating-bson-object-from-json-string)

And other
But I can not find how to create a document with a link (DBRef) to another

Something like this

```
private static final MessageFormat USER_DBREF = new MessageFormat("DBRef('organizationEntity', ObjectId('{}'))");
...
Document doc = Document.parse(json);
doc.put("organizationEntity", USER_DBREF.format(new Object[]{organizationEntity.getId()}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   doc.put("organization", new DBRef("organizationEntity", new ObjectId(organizationEntity.getId())));
```

http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.14/com/mongodb/DBRef.html