# JSON to BSON conversion

Tags: json, converters, bson

I have game files in BSON. Wanted to convert it to JSON to find the value I wanted to change. Found this site: http://mcraiha.github.io/tools/BSONhexToJSON/bsonfiletojson.html, which is the tool to do that. But now I'm stuck with JSON file, and can't get it back to BSON. I couldn't find any online tools that can reverse that process.

So my question is - is there an easy way to convert JSON to BSON?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating BSON object from JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117167/creating-bson-object-from-json-string)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I want just BSON file, not object in Java :/

Comment: you got the solution for this?@Billy.pl

Comment: No, I didn't :/ I found this site: https://onlinejsontools.com/convert-json-to-bson where in the "coming soon" section is JSON to BSON converter, but it's still not ready. You can contact author though.