# JSONObject - How to get a value?

Tags: java, json

I'm using a java class on http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html.

The following is my code snippet:

```
String jsonResult = UtilMethods.getJSON(this.jsonURL, null);
json = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
```

`getJSON` returns the following string

```
{"LabelData":{"slogan":"AWAKEN YOUR SENSES","jobsearch":"JOB SEARCH","contact":"CONTACT","video":"ENCHANTING BEACHSCAPES","createprofile":"CREATE PROFILE"}}
```

How do I get the value of 'slogan'?

I tried all the methods listed on the page, but none of them worked.

Comment: Just FYI, something like Jackson can be anlot faster and easier than using the json reference implementation.

Comment: @Jon7 // Thank you for the suggestion. I will try out Jackson. I'm new to Java..Thanks :)

Comment: what library is that ? json-simple?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
String loudScreaming = json.getJSONObject("LabelData").getString("slogan");
```

Comment: How would we do this with GSON?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally, you can do the folowing:                                                             ```String temp = json.get("labelData").getAsString();```

Comment: What is "json" variable type here ?

Comment: @vikramvi That refers to the question, where `json` was a `JSONObject`.

Comment: suggestion from @Sanevent works with `google-gson` library not `org.json`

Answer (score 10):

If it's a deeper key/value you're after and you're **not dealing with arrays** of keys/values at each level, you could recursively search the tree:

```
public static String recurseKeys(JSONObject jObj, String findKey) throws JSONException {
    String finalValue = "";
    if (jObj == null) {
        return "";
    }

    Iterator<String> keyItr = jObj.keys();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    while(keyItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keyItr.next();
        map.put(key, jObj.getString(key));
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : (map).entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(findKey)) {
            return jObj.getString(key);
        }

        // read value
        Object value = jObj.get(key);

        if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            finalValue = recurseKeys((JSONObject)value, findKey);
        }
    }

    // key is not found
    return finalValue;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String extract = recurseKeys(jObj, "extract");
```

Using Map code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4149555/2301224

Comment: Implementation has a bug(s): (1) while-loop is continuing even after recursive call returns a legitimate value. (2) you have no way to differentiate between, key not found vs key has legitimate value as "". That said, you are calling keys() method on JSONObject which sort of indicates that here JSONObject is nothing but Map. Moreover, you are anyway iterating keys() in JSONObject then why to explicitly converting it into the Map?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful while searching keys present in **nested objects** and **nested arrays**. And this is a generic solution to all cases.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MyClass
{
    public static Object finalresult = null;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException
    {
        System.out.println(myfunction(myjsonstring,key));
    }

    public static Object myfunction(JSONObject x,String y) throws JSONException
    {
        JSONArray keys =  x.names();
        for(int i=0;i<keys.length();i++)
        {
            if(finalresult!=null)
            {
                return finalresult;                     //To kill the recursion
            }

            String current_key = keys.get(i).toString();

            if(current_key.equals(y))
            {
                finalresult=x.get(current_key);
                return finalresult;
            }

            if(x.get(current_key).getClass().getName().equals("org.json.JSONObject"))
            {
                myfunction((JSONObject) x.get(current_key),y);
            }
            else if(x.get(current_key).getClass().getName().equals("org.json.JSONArray"))
            {
                for(int j=0;j<((JSONArray) x.get(current_key)).length();j++)
                {
                    if(((JSONArray) x.get(current_key)).get(j).getClass().getName().equals("org.json.JSONObject"))
                    {
                        myfunction((JSONObject)((JSONArray) x.get(current_key)).get(j),y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Possibilities:

1. "key":"value"
2. "key":{Object}
3. "key":[Array]

Logic :

- I check whether the current key and search key are the same, if so I return the value of that key.
- If it is an object, I send the value recursively to the same function.
- If it is an array, I check whether it contains an object, if so I recursively pass the value to the same function.

Comment: can you please answer to this que?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329223/how-to-update-existing-json-file-in-java/60329607#60329607

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below function to get value from JSON string,

```
public static String GetJSONValue(String JSONString, String Field)
{
       return JSONString.substring(JSONString.indexOf(Field), JSONString.indexOf("\n", JSONString.indexOf(Field))).replace(Field+"\": \"", "").replace("\"", "").replace(",","");   
}
```