# Convert JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I have a Json object like,

```
{"Id":1492,"name":"Antony","School":"National School"}
```

Now I need to separate these object. I want to get something like this,

```
Id = 1492
name = Antony
School = National School
```

So that I need to store this data separately in db table.

Please help.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

use 
http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("{\"Id\":1492,\"name\":\"Antony\",\"School\":\"National School\"}");
System.out.println("id=" + json.get("Id"));
System.out.println("name=" + json.get("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you-

```
  var data = '{"Id":1492,"name":"Antony","School":"National School"}';
  var json = JSON.parse(data);

  var Id = json["Id"];
```

or

```
  var Id = json.Id;
```

Comment: Sorry, You can find your answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451600/jsonobject-how-to-get-a-value