# How to get key value from JSON Object having nested object

Tags: getjson

I want to get the value of the `message` property in Java:

```
{ "responseStatus": { "message": "Success" } }
```

I did this:

```
lJsonObj.getString("??")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSONObject - How to get a value ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451600/jsonobject-how-to-get-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a nested json object with this:

```
JSONObject nestedJsonObject = rootJsonObject.getJSONObject("responseStatus");
```

You can get a string from a json object with this:

```
String message = nestedJsonObject.getString("message");
```

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Comment: I want to use slurper parsing. Where I am passing json Xpath from a variable. like def JsonXpath = 'error.errorDetails.errorText' slurper = new JsonSlurper()
          json = slurper.parseText(responseJsonGP)
     log.info "json ####" +json
         resValue = json.(aGlobalProperties[i].toObject)