# Javascript Object to Java List

Tags: java, javascript, json, jersey

I have the following type of JSON I want to send to Java (I'm using Jersey and the default JSON Parser it comes with)

```
{ "something" : "1", "someOtherThing" : "2" , ... }
```

But instead of creating an Object with all these properties in Java, I would like to have a Single HashMap (or whatever) that will allow me to still have access to the Key and the Value

Is such a thing possible?

I don't really have any code that does the transformation, I use Jersey like this

```
    @POST
    @Path("/purchase")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public StatusResult purchase(UserPurchaseRequest upr) {     
    }
```

If i put properties something and someOtherThing as Strings in my UserPurchaseRequest object, everything will come in fine, but I want to have everything in one structure (because I don't know how many values I will get, and I need their names as well)

Comment: Show us the code you're using that turns a JSON text into a Java object.

Comment: You need JSON to MAP. Its already answered in SO
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But still, it depends on what JSON java API you are using. For example using Jackson JSON you can create HashMap json string like this

```
  ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
  String json = pbj.writeValue(<HashMap object>);
```

or vice-versa

```
  HashMap obj = obj.readValue(json, HashMap.class);
```

Note - org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a Property to your Object like this

```
    private HashMap<String,String> purchaseValues;
```

Jersey takes care of the rest, for some reason while you are debugging, most of the entries appear as null in the HashMap