# How to easily parse json in these situations

Tags: java, json, xpath

Currently I am doing a java program and I need to parse json message from the server. I wanted to do it using Gson from google, but all I see from the docs and web are how to convert a class to json and vice versa. Maybe I misunderstood Gson, but I didn't find what I need.

So, as the type of messages is variant and the structure may change, I may need to parse the messages in following ways:

1. get value from a key

   ```
   String value = jsonParser.get(key);
   ```

   as in xpath i always do xpath.evaluate("//key", doc)
2. get a structure from a key

   so there may be predefined structure like

   ```
   class Address{
       Srting street;
       String city;
       ...
       // and other fields or methods needed
   }
   ```

   I may want to get the object in a simple way. And I may not know where this infomation is located in the json message.
3. get the value with constraints

   for example, I may want to know a persons name if he lives in '4 Five Oaks'. (address is the child node of person)

And I prefer java api or small jar packages, not a jar that needs a whole apache project to support.

Comment: Yes you should put your `PS` into a new question. I removed it here.

Answer (score 0):

in the usual scenario, when using Java, the client would know what type of object is supposed to be received either by unifying massage structure or by requesting from a different url / query.

anyway, if you prefer to first parse json to string map, take a look at the first answer of [Convert Json to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map)

also, as stated in the above link, a complete (long) list of JSON Java libraries can be found at json.org

Comment: Yes, I should know the probable structure. If something is wrong, there will be a return code 201 with a error message, then the json is short. Another example, if I request to go north, the client may return '"loacateion":"forest"', aftered by a structure of forest. But sometimes it may return lake or others. So I won't predict the exact structure. Do I make it clear?