# Fasterxml ObjectNode to MongoDB - Java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, fasterxml

Hello I have some Json data in form of a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode and I want to store it in a MongoDB.

How can the ObjectNode efficiently be converted to a MongoDB DBObject and vice versa?

Comment: Have you looked at [MongoJack](http://mongojack.org/)?  It's a nice library to work with Jackson and MongoDB

Comment: Thank you, MongoJack looks like a very good recommendation :)

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple mapping, most tools from http://json.org (section java) would work. For one of them (Jackson, http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes), you'd do:

```
HashMap<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
```

(where JSON_SOURCE is a File, input stream, reader, or json content String)
see: [Convert Json to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map/583634#583634)

Specifically for inserting an ObjectNode into mongodb you could do the following if you're using Java:

```
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
HashMap<String, Object> keyValuePairs = new ObjectMapper().readValue(TheObjectNode.traverse(), HashMap.class);
dbObject.putAll(keyValuePairs);
```