# Get a specific word in a String

Tags: java, html, string

Hi I'm trying to get information from a huge string, the thing is that I need to extract some words after a tag. I think this example will explain it better. I send a code to a web page and it returns me a String like this:

```
String CodeISend= "JFK";
//The process of getting the returned String isn't important right now

String returnedCode="{"airport":{"fs":"JFK","iata":"JFK","icao":"KJFK","faa":"JFK","name":"John F. Kennedy International Airport","street1":"JFK Airport","city":"New York""
```

I need to extract the name of the airport and save it into a separate String. But I really don't know how to get the info after "name": Appreciate the help!

Comment: Is that meant to be JSON?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm getting the code using the api in https://developer.flightstats.com/

Comment: What does the API say? Look into it. If it's JSON, use a JSON parser.

Comment: Got it! it says is JSON so I'll use the JSon parser

Comment: A few options: Gson, Jackson, org.json, flexjson, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert this from json into a map and lookup your airport using "name" as a key:  map.get(key)

See this discussion:
[Convert Json to Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/json-to-map)

and here to learn more about maps:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html