# IntelliJ IDE shows Gson successfully converts strings to objects, but when I export to Jar it says "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gson

I have two text files: PatientForms.txt and MasterCodeList.txt.

Each file holds a JSON string on each line. I use the following method to read in the contents of the file and store it in a SortedMap for example.

Here is my ServiceCode.java code:

```
public class ServiceCode {

//class variables
@SerializedName("code")
private String code;

@SerializedName("description")
private String description;

@SerializedName("cost")
private double fullRetailPrice;

//constructor: default - creates an empty code that can be modified by user
public ServiceCode() {
    setCode("Empty");
    setDescription("Empty");
    setFullRetailPrice(0.0);
}

//constructor: non-default - creates a code with values passed to it for code, description, and fullRetailPrice
public ServiceCode(String code, String description, double fullRetailPrice) {
    setCode(code);
    setDescription(description);
    setFullRetailPrice(fullRetailPrice);
}

//setters
public void setCode(String code) { this.code = code; }
public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
public void setFullRetailPrice(double fullRetailPrice) { this.fullRetailPrice = fullRetailPrice; }

//getters
public String getCode() { return code; }
public String getDescription() { return description; }
public double getFullRetailPrice() { return fullRetailPrice; }
```

Here is my method that reads in the file and places it in a map:

```
public class CodeFileHandler {

//static final File dir = new File(".");
static final Gson gson = new Gson();

public SortedMap<String, ServiceCode> loadCodeList() {
    SortedMap<String, ServiceCode> map = new TreeMap<>();
    List<String> codeStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        String loc = "MasterCodeList.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loc));

        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            codeStrings.add(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        // line is not visible here.
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String s : codeStrings) {
        //used to show that string is a valid JSON format
        System.out.println(s);

        ServiceCode c = gson.fromJson(s, ServiceCode.class);
        map.put(c.getCode(), c);
    }

    return map;
}
```

So, the problem is that this works without error in IntelliJ, but when I run it from my jar file I get an error. The string as output by the IDE when I run the program shows a valid format:

```
{"code":"D0120","description":"Periodic oral evaluation-established pt","cost":39.0}
```

When I run it from the jar file I get this:

> F:\BLCHC_MCv1\out\artifacts\BLCHC_MCv1_jar>java -jar BLCHC_MCv1.jar
>   ï»¿{"code":"D0120","description":"Periodic oral evaluation-established pt","cost":39.0}
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
>           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
>           at com.olsen.blchc.CodeFileHandler.loadCodeList(CodeFileHandler.java:39)

All sources I have looked at for the last couple of days point to the string being read in having a " in place of a { at the beginning. This is not the case.

Does anybody know why this would happen? It has no problem loading from a different file when I access PatientForms.txt, even when it is run from the jar.

**UPDATE!**

I changed my loadCodeList method to this:

```
  public void loadCodeList() {
    try {
        String loc = "MasterCodeList.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loc));

        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            ServiceCode s = gson.fromJson(line, ServiceCode.class);
            codeMap.put(s.getCode(), s);
        }
        // line is not visible here.
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My code reads in each line and converts it to a ServiceCode object from the string in JSON format, using `gson.fromJson(String, ServiceCode);` where String is the JSON string read in from the file.

**OUTPUT FROM IntelliJ IDE**

[IDE Output: No Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajFGa.png)

In the IDE I can run everything without fail and access the ServiceCode objects in my SortedMap.

**JAR FILE OUTPUT**
[JAR FILE CONSOLE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQVHd.png)

Am I not packaging my jar file correctly? I included the Gson Jar inside of my Jar directory.

Comment: This exception says that json file begins with string. So change to `String s = gson.fromJson(s, String.class);`

Comment: I tried that but it just gave me an error, saying: no instance(s) of  type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to ServiceCode interface variable T has incompatible bounds:equality constraints:String upper bounds: Object, ServiceCode

Answer (score 0):

It took a lot of hours and I finally found a way to do it without errors! I was reading how to save load my map (saved in a JSON file with full formatting and everyting) and I came upon this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32066515/8250178. Now it works when I run it from my .jar file as well as in my IDE.