# Unmarshal JSON into map

Tags: json, dictionary, go

I have a really simple JSON file, something like this, but with thousands of strings:

```
{"fruits":["apple","banana","cherry","date"]}
```

and I want to load the fruits into a

```
map[string]interface{}
```

What is the best method? Is there a way where I don't need to iterate over each element and insert into the map using a loop?

Comment: Try to implement some code, and ask specific question regarding the code. The community is in a better position to solve your problems in that aspect.

Comment: You could see the link bellow, it helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map

Comment: Thanks Victor, I'm looking for something similar in Go. Using the "usual" unmarshal example I can get a map, but it will contain the whole fruits part in one, and I still need to iterate over it when adding them to a new map - if I understood the go examples well.

Comment: Hi you can create a list of strings: https://play.golang.org/p/qDc3kn1JjE

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to define a struct for this if it only contains a slice?

Comment: This is one of the most asked Go questions on SE. Try searching, or reading the docs. When you're stuck, show us your code to ask for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is example how you can Unmarshal to string list without any struct.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

func main() {
    src_json := []byte(`{"fruits":["apple","banana","cherry","date"]}`)
    var m map[string][]string
    err := json.Unmarshal(src_json, &m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", m["fruits"][0]) //apple
 }
```

Or instead of String list you can use
`map[string][]interface{}`