# Get Value from JSON into Map, then value out of the Map

Tags: java, json, iterator

I have the following JSON data:

JSON:

```
[{
"valInternalCode": "NE",
"valMinimumInputString": "NE",
"valExternalRepresentation": "Northeast",
"valActionCode1": "1",
"valActionCode2": null,
"valActionCode3": null,
"valActionCode4": null,
"id": {
    "valcodeId": "X.LOCATION",
    "pos": 1
},
"uniqueId": "X.LOCATION-1",
"caption": "Northeast"
}, {
"valInternalCode": "NW",
"valMinimumInputString": "NW",
"valExternalRepresentation": "Northwest",
"valActionCode1": "1",
"valActionCode2": null,
"valActionCode3": null,
"valActionCode4": null,
"id": {
    "valcodeId": "X.LOCATION",
    "pos": 2
},
"uniqueId": "X.LOCATION-2",
"caption": "Northwest"
```

}

I am able to parse it and create a Map from the data like so:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Map>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Map> dataCollection = gson.fromJson(jsonString.toString(), collectionType);
```

I can then iterate through it and get a value that I need using the Key like so:

```
 iterator.next().get("valInternalCode");
```

What I am struggling with is how to get something that is inside of the id field:

```
"id": {
"valcodeId": "X.LOCATION",
"pos": 2
},
```

I am using Hibernate to get the data from a non normalized Oracle database (that is why hibernate creates the id field the way it does)

EDIT:

My attempt at an ugly way of doing it.  Basically looping within the loop:

```
while (valIterator.hasNext()) {
  Map currentVal = valIterator.next();
  String valId = "";

  Collection<Map> idVal = (Collection<Map>) currentVal.get("id");
  Iterator<Map> valIdIterator = idVal.iterator();

  while (valIdIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map valIdCurrentVal = valIdIterator.next();

    valId = valIdCurrentVal.get("valcodeId").toString();
  }
}
```

Getting a ClassCastException when I try to cast    currentVal.get("id") to a Collection

Comment: What have you tried?  Was an exception thrown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map

Comment: @CardinalSystem Well the only thing I have tried is to iterate inside the while loop of my other iterator, but am wondering if there is another way.  I am in the process of getting that code "working" but will post again if I do

Comment: @CardinalSystem post edited, thanks.

Comment: I am guessing that you dont have to iterate over the id, since its a JSONObject, you should be able to fetch values out from it.