# convert array to map using spring mvc with jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, java-8

From my service I am generating the JSON based on the language.I need to covert the array to the map which contains one value as key and another as value (lot of value in the arrays based on the database).

I have written the code I am getting the array and only "I need to convert into the list of key value pair like the given sample and write in the text file.

JSON from my service

```
[
[
    "task",
    "Comments"
],
[
    "CUSTOM_43_01",
    "Email"
],
[
    "CUSTOM_44_02",
    "Mobile"
],..........
]
```

Comment: I think it would happen if you returned a Map instead of a LIst.

Comment: display `LanguageDTO` properties please!

Comment: Your expected response is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @HadiJ i have added the DTO's

Comment: As per the previous comments, A map would get you closer to your result. Also a map literal would separate key/value with a colon instead of an equal. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/443499/744133.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your result from repository to expected result in the service like bellow:

```
public Map<String,String> getAllLangaugeDataForEn(Integer appId, String language) {
  Map<String,String> result = new HashMap();
  if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("EN")) {
   result  = languageRepository.getEnLanguageList(appId)
            .stream()
            .map(language-> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(language.getX(),language.getY()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
   }
     return result;
}
```

`language.getX()` and `language.getY()` are `LanguageDTO` getters methods(LanguageDTO properties)!

Comment: I am getting The method stream() is undefined for the type Map<String,String> error

Comment: I have added my DTO

Comment: well, you tagged `java-8` due to this reason I put this answer. what is your java version?

Comment: java version is java -8

Comment: the`languageRepository.getEnLanguageList(appId)` result is list so `stream()` is defined for it. can you display or say in detail your error?