# How to convert jsonarray into map or something else format which can be compared with datastax value

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have JSON Array which I want to convert in some format which I can compare with datastax value.
I tried below code:

String familyNames = response.jsonPath().getString("FAMILY");

and

List jsonresponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");

I am not able to find any way.
I expect a format in which I  can comapre entire json response with the values in datastax table

Answer (score 0):

Consider blogs such as [this one](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/) or [this one](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-convert-json-array-string-to-list/) or posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map) or this one [here](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

....
String json = "[{\"name\":\"mkyong\", \"age\":37}, {\"name\":\"fong\", \"age\":38}]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, Person[].class));
```

Or

```
String jsonString = "{'Bob' : {'name': 'Bob Willis'},"
    + "'Jenny' : {'name': 'Jenny McCarthy'}, "
    + "'Steve' : {'name': 'Steven Waugh'}}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type empMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Employee>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Employee> nameEmployeeMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, empMapType);
```